# Is it possible to customize upper or lower filters in a Hardware Profile?

Tags: windows, registry, hardware, device-driver, wdk

To set a filter driver on a specific class of devices, you have to modify its `UpperFilters` or `LowerFilters` MULTI_SZ registry value. For example, to attach an upper filter to all devices belonging to the USB device class, you'd modify the following value (probably through DpInst etc.):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{36FC9E60-C465-11CF-8056-444553540000}\UpperFilters
```

Is it possible to make this change specific to a Hardware Profile? --that is, to attach the filter driver only in a specific hardware profile?

My goal is that, in the event of a bug inadvertently introduced during development which causes the filter driver to crash on startup, it would be easy to boot the machine without the crashing driver. (Safe Mode also solves this, but takes a while more to boot up.)